# Display link to a controller action on a user's profile if logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Devise to manage user authentication in my Rails app and I would like to display a button on a user's profile page if they are logged in. Clicking on the button should link to a "new" action in a controller. We'll call this controller Works. A User has many Works. Clicking on the button will allow the User to add a new Work to his/her profile.

I currently have the button in the view but there is no check to only show this button on their own profile. Here is the view:

```
<%= link_to "Add work", { :controller => 'works', :action => 'new' }, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-small' -%>
```

The button works fine and will send the user to /works/new. However, how can I have this button only appear on one's own profile page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the button in an if block:

```
  <% if current_user == @user %>

    <%= link_to "Add work", { :controller => 'works', :action => 'new' }, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-small' -%>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

with devise, current_user is a helper method so just doing

```
<% if current_user %>
```

works